# Twitter Bootstrap- Can't get Carousel to change image

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I have copied the HTML below- I do not know why, but when i open this in a browser it is stuck on the first image and wont transition... I have included all the code below of my html. The CSS and JS files are the generic bootstrap files provided.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Bootstrap test site</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css" type="text/css">

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.carousel').carousel();
    });
    </script>



</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

    <div class="span8"> <img src="img/logo_title.png"> </div> 

        <div>

            <div id="this-carousel-id" class="carousel slide">
              <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Caption text here1</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Caption text here2</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Caption text here3</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                  <img src="http://placehold.it/1200x480" alt="" />
                  <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <p>Caption text here4</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div><!-- /.carousel-inner -->
              <!--  Next and Previous controls below
                    href values must reference the id for this carousel -->
                <a class="carousel-control left" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
                <a class="carousel-control right" href="#this-carousel-id" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
            </div><!-- /.carousel -->
        </div>  

    </div>

<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any of the JS libraries in bootstrap, make sure that you include the actual library. In your case, you left out the carousel library. Other Bootstrap add-ons that require separate js files include modals, dropdowns, and tooltips. 
Add it in:

```
 <script src="/js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

You also included bootstrap.js twice.

Comment: Where do I get that file?  On the Bootstrap site it says "Individual or compiled
Plugins can be included individually (though some have required dependencies), or all at once. Both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.min.js contain all plugins in a single file."               Therefore; if it includes them, why do i need to add another file?

Comment: pull the main github repository git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap.git or download just what you need: https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/tree/master/js

Comment: I've downloaded and included the file and it still doesn't work.  Sorry Im  a major newb with JS. @munch1324

Comment: sorry, I just noticed you also are missing jquery. I edited my answer to also include that.

Comment: I must be mistaken, but i was led to believe the google library jquery script covered that?

Comment: Yup! Works now. Thank you!

Comment: No problem, for future debugging I would recommend using a web debugger such as chrome's developer tools (F12). Usually when something is not working there will be a JS error (in this case it would have probably said something along the lines of 'Object has no method carousel')